# Invalid argument error with tab in listchars

Tags: vimrc

I used `list` and `listchars` in vimrc file to display hidden characters but I get this error:

```
E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:>
```

after `tab:>` there is also a space. Below I have the complete entries

```
set list
set listchars=tab:> ,trail:-,space:·
```

I checked the arguments one by one, and the problem is caused when I also include the `tab` argument.
I saw that in many cases specifying encoding to `utf-8` solves the problem, so at the top of the file I inserted the lines

```
set encoding=utf-8
scriptencoding utf-8
```

but the problem remains. Currently the `tab` character is displayed as `^I`.

I run vim version 8.2 in Debian 11.6

How can I solve the tab character problem?

I want to include it in my specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` command doesn't accept space in the left hand side (space is used to separate right hand sides). You have to escape the spaces:

```
set list
set listchars=tab:>\ ,trail:-,space:·
```

Comment: Thank you @Vivian De Smedt, now it works perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) You are welcome! Thanks for the feedback.